# how to execute a batch file from a website

Tags: javascript, batch-file, scripting, web

I know this sounds fishy, but I'm trying to run a batch file from a website. Our users are seniors that wouldn't know how to do anything with a computer. Our software is a replacement for the windows shell. When the computer starts, it automatically starts our software and nothing else. Our users never see windows, only our application. It is written in C# and after presenting a login screen shows the user a full-screen web application.

We have a system where we update our application via a batch file it downloads by itself. However, the dialog window asking the user for an update is broken (minimized, so the user doesn't see it). Now our users can't update our application. We fixed this bug in the current version, but users can't get the new version.

Is there any way to run a batch file from a website? The batch file is already downloaded by our application, it just needs to run. It is located in c:/users/the_user/appdata/roaming/. If anyone has any idea how we could run the batch file remotely, that would be awesome.

**I know it would be a huge security risk if something like this is possible, please don't point that out to me.** It is also not their computer that runs the software, but one we provide for the purpose of the application. If a user does not want to use the app anymore, we take the computer back as well. There can not be any personal data saved on it, because there is simply no way for the user to get it on there.

Our update process goes like this: the C# app downloads a zip from our web-server if there is a new version -> the app asks the user if he/she wants to install that update -> if the user presses yes, the c# app closes and runs the batch file that copies the contents from the zip to the folder where our c# app resides -> at the end of the batch file is a system restart command, after restarting the tablet our app starts up and the user can continue using it.

Comment: If you completely control the software, you can provide an extended browser that allows whatever you want.

Comment: Um, why in the world don't you have some sort of auto updater installed when the software is installed in the first place?

Comment: @Pointy We already do that, the problem is that in the version users currently have, something like this is not implemented.

Comment: @epascarello We have an updater installed, it just needs to run. We made our application so that the user has to press yes on a dialog asking him/her to update and in the current version this dialog is minimised.

Comment: If you've made a product for people who don't get modern computer interfaces, and it requires them to manually approve software updates, well I think that's your problem :-)

Comment: @Pointy They can handle a simple yes/no

Comment: So are you running a web app on a single PC? Does this thing function as a web server for other PCs browsing to it?  What's the OS?  What's on the backend, IIS? How would running a batch file help them?  Can you teach them to Alt-tab (or Ctrl-tab) to change focus to the minimized dialog?

Comment: @Tony No, we are running a C# app on a tablet (there is no keyboard), running windows 8. The application loads a webpage in the built in chrome browser where users can make video calls (kinda like a fullscreen skype experience). The problem is that the dialog asking to update is minimised. We also have a built in teamviewer app that users can use to request remote support from us. We could ask all of our users to press the teamviewer button, but that would mean calling all of them separately and there are simply too many. I updated the question with the update process.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't launch a batch file from a website.

A browser will just save it to the local drive or open it in the web page.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, the file is already saved to disk, it just needs to be run.

Comment: `cmd /c "c:\folder\batchname.bat"`  That is one way to launch a batch file.

Comment: Yes Kev you have a problem and you can't launch a batch file.  I confirmed that it can't be done with a web browser.

Comment: @AlexTartan  You're very keen to post to an answer that was posted over 2 years ago, but my answer and comment was accurate at the time - the OP added the critical information afterward and didn't notify me that he'd done so.

Comment: @foxidrive, Sorry, this showed up in my review list. Otherwise I (probably) wouldn't have seen it. Indeed I didn't check the post date. It's a lesson leaned.